# External monitor is black with only cursor visible and responsive -> connected according to xrandr

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I am having troubles connecting an external monitor in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Xrandr can identify it (HDMI) but only the cursor is shown. I am using the NVIDIA driver "X.Org X server - Nouveau..."  in a Lenovo P73 (Graphics: Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)). Can anyone help me?

```
HDMI-1-1 connected 1680x1050+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+  59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    59.93  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900      59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    60.00    59.94    59.74  
   1024x768      75.05    60.04    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   960x720       75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x512       75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    75.00    72.81    75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       70.08  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32
```

More system info:

```
System:    Kernel: 5.0.0-37-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: LENOVO product: 20QSS0RM00 v: ThinkPad P73 serial: N/A
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 20QSS0RM00 v: SDK0T08861 WIN serial: N/A
           UEFI: LENOVO v: N2NET33W (1.18 ) date: 11/05/2019
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 3e9b
           Card-2: NVIDIA Device 1eb6
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.4 ) drivers: i915,nouveau
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.01hz, 1680x1050@59.95hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.8
```

From `journalctl`:

```
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1700]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event18);
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1700]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
```

And the strange thing is that the monitor is detected and I can see and move the cursor, but the background is pitch black.

Comment: `ubuntu-drivers` command might help. Also the output of `inxi -SMG -! 31 -y 80`

Comment: thanks Pablo. I updated the comment with more info about the system

Comment: Already tried `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`?

Comment: yes, I tried "ubuntu-drivers devices" and "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall" but remains the same. I tried also to edit "/etc/default/grub" (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048339/black-second-screen-after-18-04-update) but nothing. The interesting thing is that the screen is black but I can see and move the cursor there...

Comment: You are using nouveau (open source) drivers, did you tried with the proprietary ones? Software&Updates > Additional Drivers. Read the logs `journalctl -b -p warning`

Comment: Yes, I tried `nvidia-driver-435` (proprietary, tested) and `nvidia-driver-430` (proprietary), but it gets even worse as the monitor/hdmi stops being detected. `journalctl` shows the following issue though: 

`/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1700]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event18); 
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1700]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.` And the strange thing is that the monitor is detected and I can see and move  the cursor, but the background is pitch black.

Comment: I have the same problem!

Comment: I have the same problem, and I would prefer not to switch from nouveau to proprietary nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell precision 7550.

What worked for me was:

- Turn Secure boot off.
- Run ([thanks Pablo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203321/external-monitor-is-black-with-only-cursor-visible-and-responsive-connected-a/1338788#comment2018501_1203321)):

  ```
  sudo ubuntu-drivers install
  ```
- Restart.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and that did not work for me.
The solution was uninstalling all nvidia drivers and use the open source driver for my GPU. go to `Software & Updates` -> `Additional Drivers` --> `Using X.Org X Server (open source)`.

This option was blocked for me so I had to uninstall the nvidia drivers I had(probably the root cause of the issue). After uninstalling  my nvidea drivers and selection the open source driver I was able to fix the issue. Probably reinstalling the nvidea drivers will also work now.

To find the nvidia drivers installed I used `sudo dpkg -l | grep nvidia` 
and just deleted them with `sudo dpkg -P {nvidia-driver-xxx}`

Works after rebooting